# Distributed Cache Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, distributedcache

I'm trying to resolve an error related to Distributed Cache, but have been unsuccessful in all of my attempts.

Here is the error from the event logs:

```
Session "WSSUSAGESESSION15" failed to start with the following error:  0xC0000035
```

I have verified the service is on-line using the following:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status
```

I've also trying removing/adding a new Distributed Cache instance:

```
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Comment: What is your farm topology? How many servers in the Distributed cache role?

Comment: This is a single server (Dev/Test) Windows Server 2012 R2, SQL Server 2012 R2, 8 Core, 16 gb Memory